# Is it possible to use lazy dynamic linking on Linux?

Tags: linux, ld

On UNIX, I may use a commandline like:

```
cc -o executable *.o -zlazyload -lsomelib
```

with the result that the libraries listed to the right of `-zlazyload` are marked with the LAZYLOAD ELF tag in the binary. This may be verified by calling `dump -Lv executable` and the result contains e.g.:

```
  **** DYNAMIC SECTION INFORMATION ****
.dynamic:
[INDEX] Tag         Value
[1]     POSFLAG_1       LAZYLOAD
[2]     NEEDED          libsecdb.so.1
```

In this case, `libsecdb` is not loaded at the startup time of the executable, but delayed to the time, when the first function from `libsecdb` is called.

This trick may be used to keep the incore representation of the executable smaller if it does not use all features.

Is there a way to achive the same on Linux? The GNU linker seems to have a flag `-zlazy`, but my experience is that this is without effect.

The background for this question is that on Solaris, it is simple to link the current Bourne Shell (bosh) using lazy linking and this results in a shell that is nearly as small as `dash` when executing shell scripts, but that is still faster than `dash`. The shared libraries for the interactive history editor are only linked if the shell is used in interactive mode.

Comment: How are you testing if -zlazy works in Linux?

Comment: E.g. by linking `bosh` this way on Linux and calling `bosh -c 'pmap $$;:'` and comparing the result with the result from Solaris.

Comment: @schily. UNIX is a brand, Unix is an operating system.

Comment: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Quality_Assurance/As-needed ?

Comment: @fpmurphy The original tests have been done on a UNIX certified platform. Linux is not certified.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov The documented and observed behavior for the feature you mentioned is related to the fact wheather a library is added to the list of needed dependencies at all. The expected behavior would be delayed linking for certain libraries, so this is not usable.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I think that there are two things.

1. loading (that is, mmap'ing the shared library into memory) and
2. binding (that is, resolving symbols)

On Linux, `-zlazy` turns on lazy binding (and it is the default, so adding it changes nothing). I'm not aware of any lazy loading on Linux.

Comment: Illumos (ex OpenSolaris) linker source code is [here](https://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/cmd/sgs/libld/common/). To me if anyone wants to port this feature to Linux is more than welcome.